# How can I make this query run in MySQL (still in one query)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, and I've tried a few variations, but it will not run for various different reasons:

```
UPDATE `table1` 
    SET `col1`='1',`col2`='1' 
        WHERE `col3`='302' && `col4`='136' && 
            `col5`=(SELECT MAX(`col5`) 
                FROM `table1` 
                    WHERE `col3`='302' && `col4`='136')
```

Comment: can you add some information as to why it won't run?

Comment: Because the query is wrong. The error was `You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`. Notulysses answered it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AND` instead of `&&`. Also if col`N` types are numeric you don't have to use single quotes.

```
UPDATE `table1` 
SET `col1`='1',`col2`='1' 
WHERE `col3`='302' 
  AND `col4`='136' 
  AND `col5` = (SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT MAX(`col5`) 
                 FROM `table1` 
                 WHERE `col3`='302' AND `col4`='136') x)
```

Comment: This gives the same error, which is `You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace `&&` with `AND` and it should works